# Print Macro - Run-time error 1004. Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is, if there is a "1" in column A* then I want the macro to copy the rows, from column B*:L* to a new worksheet, then print the worksheet when it is has gone through the complete range.

If there is no "1" in column A then I just want it to continue to the next row to check. Would love some help?

```
Sub PrintFlaggedRows()
  Const STARTSEARCHROW As Long = 1
  Const STARTPRINTROW As Long = 2
  Const ENDSEARCHROW As Long = 250
  Const STARTCOLUMN As Integer = 1 ' Column A
  Const ENDCOLUMN As Integer = 1   ' Column A
  Dim oldAlerts As Boolean
  Dim oldUpdates As Boolean
  Dim destSheet As Worksheet
  Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
  Dim destRange As Range
  Dim i As Long


  oldUpdates = Application.ScreenUpdating
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  oldAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Set srcSheet = Sheets("Estimating & Building Quote")
  Set destSheet = Worksheets.Add
  Set destRange = destSheet.Cells(STARTPRINTROW, 1)

  For i = STARTSEARCHROW To ENDSEARCHROW

        If (srcSheet.Cells(i, 1) = 1) _
              Or (srcSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "1") Then

              srcSheet.Range(Cells(i, STARTCOLUMN), Cells(i, ENDCOLUMN)).Copy
              dstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              dstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

              Set dstRange = dstRange.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
  Next i

  destSheet.Columns.AutoFit
  destSheet.PrintOut

  destSheet.Delete

  Application.DisplayAlerts = oldAlerts
  Application.ScreenUpdating = oldUpdates
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
srcSheet.Range(Cells(i, STARTCOLUMN), Cells(i, ENDCOLUMN)).Copy
```

Here the unqualified `Cells()` refers always to the ActiveSheet, which may not be what you want.

Try:

```
With srcSheet
    .Range(.Cells(i, STARTCOLUMN), .Cells(i, ENDCOLUMN)).Copy
End With
```

Comment: After that I get a Run-time error '424': Object required.  When I debug line `dstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is highlighted.

Comment: If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module you'll see that you have declared and assigned a variable `destRange` but the line causing the error is trying to use `dstRange`.  Always using `Option Explicit` saves you from these types of errors.